# Reporting options for 2016 - opinions?

Tags: 2016, reporting-services

My organization is currently using InfoPath to enter financial data into SharePoint 2010 libraries/lists. Then, this information is utilizing Crystal Reports to then aggregate the information in a meaningful way in a report.  We are now transitioning into 2016 and are trying to figure out what solution to move forward with.

Is there any reason we shouldn't be utilizing SQL Sever Reporting services? We are trying to avoid paying a third party for services. Any opinions or thoughts would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSRS is one option, though you may want to stick to SSRS Native mode as the last version of SharePoint and SSRS that supports SSRS Integrated mode is 2016.

Another option would be Power BI + Microsoft Data Gateway.

Comment: The way our organization is set up makes it difficult via the gateway and what not. I think SSRS would be our likely go-to. I guess I'm curious what you imagine the cons would be. We are basically just taking the data and adding to get gross sums as well as displaying other information as requested. Are the reports pre-designed by the developer or are individuals able to run reports based on certain data? For example, they could select a specific individual and see all data related to that person?

Comment: It all depends on your data source. SSRS does not have any pre-built reports, a BI developer would need to create them.

Associating all data across an entire farm would not be possible -- that's really something only achievable via the Graph but would require you to use SPO.

Comment: Correct, sorry. I imagine I would be the ones building the report. I used it briefly in the past but it's been a couple of years. As far as the entire farm is concerned - no. It would be coming from a single site collection and likely only 1 or 2 lists. Our main concern is that the end-user would be able to select parameters and report as necessary.

Comment: SSRS does support parameters and of course reporting data on lists. That seems like a reasonable report to create.

Comment: Great, thanks so much for your input.